# Issue in console event listener

Tags: javascript, service-cloud-console, custom-console-components, omnichannel, consoleintegrationtoolkit

I have recently enabled omnichannel in our org. I need to perform some action when an agent accepts a post from the omnichannel widget in the console. To do this I added a hidden custom console component in the console with the below code

```
<script id="clientEventHandlersJS" language="javascript">
    var eventHandler = function (result) {
    alert('I m in');

    };
    sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.​PRESENCE.WORK_ACCEPTED(eventHandler);
</script> </apex:page>
```

But I am getting error for this page:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

And another error:

> unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'reflected-xss'. Failed
>   to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not
>   Found)

Can anyone let me know why these issues are happening?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I think function `eventHandler()` should be called something like this-- `sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.​PRESENCE.WORK_ACCEPTED(eventHandler());`

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="true" applyBodyTag="true" docType="html-5.0">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<head>
    <title>ChatAlert</title>
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/40.0/integration.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery_ui, 'js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js')}" />
</head>

<body>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 sforce.console.addEventListener(
            sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.PRESENCE.WORK_ACCEPTED,
            function (result) {
                console.log('Accepted work item: ', result);
                alert(result.workItemId);
            });
</script>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Try this code and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: please explain "how and why" your code should work, code dumps are not really useful without an explanation.